# SwiftUI - Loading image with DispatchQueue

Tags: swiftui, calendar, uikit, dispatch, dispatch-queue

I understand how to utilize DispatchQueue with UIKit, but not with SwiftUI, because HorizonCalendar requires SwiftUI to function. Everything works perfectly, however as I browse down and load an image, the scrolling lags. I attempted to add DispatchQueue, however the SwiftUI rejected it. How can I include DispatchQueue in this code so that it may load images while scrolling?

Main ViewController

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import HorizonCalendar

class TheGalleryView: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: colorTint]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = textAttributes
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = colorTint
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = getString(rawString: "Gallery")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "gear"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(openSetting))
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Main Background")
        
        createCalendar()
    }
    
    func createCalendar() {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let startDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2023))!
        let endDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2023, month: 12, day: 31))!
        
        let content = CalendarViewContent(calendar: calendar,
                                          visibleDateRange: startDate...endDate,
                                          monthsLayout: .vertical(options: VerticalMonthsLayoutOptions()))
            .interMonthSpacing(25)
            .dayItemProvider { day in
                ZStack {
                    if getFirstPhotoFromGallery(fromDay: day.components) != nil {
                        Image(uiImage: getFirstPhotoFromGallery(fromDay: day.components)!)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .cornerRadius(7)
                            .opacity(0.4)
                    }
                    Text("\(day.day)")
                        .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .semibold))
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "Font Color")!))
                }
                .calendarItemModel
            }
        
            .interMonthSpacing(24)
            .verticalDayMargin(8)
            .horizontalDayMargin(8)
        
        let calendarView = CalendarView(initialContent: content)
        calendarView.daySelectionHandler = { day in
            // MARK: The date has been selected
        }
        
        calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        calendarView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Main Background")
        view.addSubview(calendarView)
        calendarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        calendarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        calendarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        calendarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Extension code, to load the image from data core

```
func getFirstPhotoFromGallery(fromDay: DateComponents) -> UIImage? {
    var prePhoto = UIImage(systemName: "")?.withTintColor(.clear)
    
    let freshDate = Calendar.current.date(from: fromDay)
    
    let getDailyData = theDailyData.first(where: { $0.date == freshDate })
    
    if getDailyData != nil {
        let searchTheImage = thePhotoData.first(where: { $0.belongTo == getDailyData?.theID })
        if searchTheImage != nil {
            let getPhoto = UIImage(data: (searchTheImage?.thePhotoData)!)?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.25)
            prePhoto = UIImage(data: getPhoto!)
            // This doesn't accepted the return inside the DispatchQueue
        }
    }
    
    return prePhoto
}
```

Comment: You are wrongly mixing UIKit and SwiftUI concepts. Do a basic tutorial on SwiftUI first.
You cannot use things, such as `ZStack`,  `Image` and `Text`, like you do in `func createCalendar()` inside a `class TheGalleryView: UIViewController`, 
they are **only** for use in `Views`

Comment: Why are you converting to and from data? Why not return `getPhoto` without doing the `jpegData` to Data to UIImage conversion?

Comment: Although my project is heavily reliant on UIKit, HorizonCalendar needs SwiftUI. When I performed the app test, everything worked OK, however when I scrolled down, the scroll halted till the image loaded, then resumed. That's why I'm trying to find out how to scroll smoothly as the image loads.

Comment: Additionally, I'm importing a picture from Data Core, so it came from data.

Comment: Right, but you’re converting the data to an image, then back to data, then back to an image.

Comment: Alright, I'm simply trying to keep memory low, so I'm going to delete jpegData. I'm solely focusing on converting data to uiimage, which appears to be better, but there is still some lag when scrolling quickly and having a lot of photos on the calendar.